# How to use a Capture Group with gulp-replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp-replace

gulp-replace 0.5.4

**Current** via gulp and rev:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app-3c224ff086.css">
```

**Goal**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app-3c224ff086.css" media="screen">
```

**Result**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="$1" media="screen">
```

Initial test was: https://regex101.com/r/miM7TN/1 . I might have linked the test with a capture group of $0, but in my project I am using capture group 1.

In my gulp task the following is added:

```
var regex = /\"assets\/styles\/app-+.*\"/;
var subst = `$1 media="screen"`;
.pipe(replace(regex, subst))
```

My string, to include start and end quotes, is being found. Instead of a capture group I am getting a literal $1. How do I get the actual value of the capture group? The gulp-replace documentation shows a replace value '$1foo'. Similar questions on SO show '$1' and "$1", and I am not yet seeing the difference to my situation. I've tried back-ticks, single quotes, and double quotes.

Comment: `$1` refers to a capturing group with ID=1, the first `(...)`. You must use `var regex = /("assets\/styles\/app-+.*")/;` for `$1` to "work" the same way as `$&` (backreference to the whole match value) (or `$0` in the recent browser versions). Or, yes, try to replace `$0` with `$&` in your current replacement pattern.

Comment: Btw, regex101 does not recognize the valid `$&` JS backreference, it is a [bug](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/777). Test in the target environment only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. Adding the () before and after the /" fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$1` backreference refers to a capturing group with ID 1, the text captured with the first `(...)` in your pattern.

You must use

```
 var regex = /("assets\/styles\/app-+.*")/;
```

for `$1` to "work" the same way as `$&` (backreference to the whole match value).

Answer (score 1):

Your can use a callback as the second parameter in gulp-replace. The function was loop over each capture group.
Here's an example where I am converting camelCase variables to css notation

```
.pipe(replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(match){
  return '-'+match.toLowerCase()
}))

{camelCase1: 1, camelCase2: 2}
```

Becomes camel-case1 and case-case2