# replace with regex for gulp-replace

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-replace

I am using gulp replace to replace full path name with another name by matching starting and ending strings

> example

input:

```
src/app/Client/Home/home.service.js
```

output

```
dist/Home/home.service.min.js
```

---

---

```
.state('masterPage.blogArticle', {
            url: "/article/:postId",
            templateUrl: "src/app/Client/Blog/article/index.html",
            controller: "articleCtrl",
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'competitiveClient',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files
                        files: [
                            'src/app/Client/Blog/article/article.service.js',
                            'src/app/Client/Blog/article/article.controller.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
```

Here I want to replace .js file path with above output in all state

---

```
gulp.task('templates', () => {
  gulp.src(['dist/client/app/js/app.config.min.js'])
    .pipe(replace(/^(src\/app\/Client\/)(.*)(.js)$/g, 'dist/client/app'))
    .pipe(replace(/.js/g, '.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/client/app/js/'));
 });
```

but it's not working, it not getting matching path
so if anyone have idea to solve it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear what you are seeking.  What is the string in your file you  are looking to match and what do you want the final string to be after replacement?  Please edit your question.

Comment: You aren't trying to use gulp-replace to rename the file itself are you?  It only modifies text within a file not the filename itself.

Comment: @Mark I have string path as "src/app/Client/Home/home.service.js" and I want to replace string with "dist/Home/home.service.min.js" and there are many string paths with same pattern

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer - I was confused by your replace string in your code 'dist/client/app' that is misleading.

Comment: @Mark thanks but this still not working, but I have tried this
" /src\/app\/Client\/(.*?)\.*\.js/ig " it is working but it replacing all content instead of .js file only

Comment: My answer below works perfectly for me.  So you have some other issue in your file.  Show an actual cut and paste from a few lines of your file in your question above.

Comment: @Mark I have updated question, added state please have look

Comment: Updated - is that the result you wanted?

Comment: @Mark I have updated your answer in which regex is valid and it able to find .js string, but the problem is it replacing all contents

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gulp.task('templates', () => {

  return gulp.src(['dist/client/app/js/app.config.min.js'])

      // need the matching groups 2 and 3 as well, and the m flag

      //.pipe(replace(/^(src\/app\/Client\/)(.*)(.js)$/gm, 'dist/$2$3'))

      .pipe(replace(/(src\/app\/Client\/)(.*)(.js)/g, 'dist/$2$3'))

      // escape the .
      .pipe(replace(/\.js/g, '.min.js'))

      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/client/app/js/'));
});
```

---

```
src/app/Client/Home/home.service.js
```

==>

```
dist/Home/home.service.min.js
```

[And you'll want the return statement I added in there too.]

Comment: not working it is not finding string with regex and it replacing dist/client/app/$2$3 with string

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257343/2483138), `gulp-replace` will take a callback as a second argument. The only trick to that is that the full match will be the first param, all matching groups will be the second-through-nth argument, then there are a couple more.

E.G.

```
replace("my-(.*)", (full, capture) => {return "string: " + capture})
```